# How can I reduce the number of xticks displayed on a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting time series data and I would like to maintain the resolution in the curves, but I want to display fewer years on the x-axis. I've parsed the 'Year' column as dates and I've made that column into the dataframe's index. I feel like it should be easy to thin down the frequency of the labels, but everything I've tried has simply made the labels inaccurate.

The DataFrame has the form:

```
print(total_df.head())

         All ages  Age 18 or older
Year                           
1978     131.0            183.0
1979     133.0            185.0
1980     138.0            191.0
1981     153.0            211.0
1982     170.0            232.0
```

And I've been using this code to produce my plot.

```
with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
    ax.plot(total_df['All ages'])
    ax.plot(total_df['Age 18 or older'])
    ax.set_title('Total Imprisonment Rates (table: p16f01)')
    ax.set_xlabel('Year')
    ax.set_ylabel('People imprisoned (per 100k US population)')
    ax.set_xticklabels(total_df.index, rotation=70)
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1.1*max([total_df['All ages'].max(), 
                             total_df['Age 18 or older'].max()])])
```

Which produces
[image: total imprisonment plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't happen. And it wouldn't happen if you made sure your index are actual numbers, not strings.

To convert your index to numbers, use e.g.

```
df.index = df.index.values.astype(int)
```

Then remove the `set_xticklabels` line, because this would anyway only make sense if you set the ticks via `set_ticks` as well.
This will then assure that matplotlib automatically chooses useful spacings between the ticks.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(9)
import pandas as pd

inx = np.arange(1978,2017).astype(str)
a = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(inx),2), axis=0)+10
df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=inx, columns=list("AB"))

df.index = df.index.values.astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ax.plot(df['A'])
ax.plot(df['B'])

ax.set_xlabel('YEAR')

ax.legend()
ax.set_ylim([0, 1.1*max([df['A'].max(), 
                         df['B'].max()])])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This produced the plot I wanted. 

I included the argument parse_dates=['Year'] when I read in the data, but you were correct, they were still stored as strings rather than as DateTime objects.